# Make my domain to point a static IP in which my website is hosted with "/applicationName"

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, web, iis-7.5

It is very painful for me how to make my domain to point my Static IP with /application name in iis.

i have successfully pointed to my static ip but how can i point to my web site which is hosted inside / folder for example `122.33.44.55/MyApp`.
is there any way to do this? i m using iis 10 .

i have already tried domain forwarding with masking but all urls are hiding inside my domain.

Comment: Did you create an application "within" another web site in IIS? Or did you [create a _new_ web site](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/create-a-web-site)? You can use a single IP for multiple `Sites` in IIS.

Comment: i have created an application inside website

Comment: Then it's likely the "default" IIS web site and your app is one of its virtual directories. Create an entirely new `Site` if you want it to be "dedicated" (its  own web site/application) - see the link above for step by step. You'll also have to delete it from the "default IIS site" in IIS Manager (**not** saying to delete the physical files, just remove it from being a "child" of the default IIS site).  Hth.

Comment: ok i understood what you are saying.but when i create new website like website2 and add my application inside it then how can i point it with my domain which i have purchased ??. my main concern is that i want to point suppose 233.44.32.1/MyApp from my domain www.showapp.com.

Comment: See below (too long for comment). Hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ok i understood what you are saying.but when i create new website like website2 and add my application inside it then how can i point it with my domain which i have purchased ??. my main concern is that i want to point suppose 233.44.32.1/MyApp from my domain www.showapp.com

When you [create a new site in IIS](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/create-a-web-site), if you have more than 1 `Sites`, and your server only has 1 IP, or you want to share the same IP for multiple sites, then use `host headers` (#10 in the steps outlined in the link)

Actions Pane -> Edit Site -> Bindings (IIS Manager)

[image: Edit Your Site Bindings]

Screenshot shows:

- Multiple `Sites` in IIS
- The dialog boxes when you EDIT->Bindings for your `Site` - in this screenshot, I'm editing the bindings of a site I named `WebApi` (each site will have its own bindings/settings).
- Provide your server's *public IP address*
- Add host name - e.g. `www.domain.com`
- You'll likely have to do this twice - repeat steps above for host header `domain.com` (no "www")
- *Assuming* you have configured `DNS` and networking properly, you should be set.

Notes:

- The screenshot shows my local IIS server. It's not public so I don't do public DNS and just set my local `hosts` file (instead of DNS) for any host I want (not valid TLDs like `dev.webapi` above)
- There are multiple ways of setting servers up (e.g. public vs local IP in a network, etc.), and I'm not getting into detail here, so these are "general"